# Do I need to install Glassfish?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am new to glassfish server and I have a question on usage:
**can I just use glassfish like a tomcat server without needing an installation?**

Can I just take a folder containing glassfish folders, jars etc., dump it in a folder location, setup a few environment variables have it run; just like tomcat?

Is it possible with glassfish? also does glassfish installation do any other background things like creating registry entries etc., other than creating the glassfish folder structure?

Answer (score 2):

There are instructions on [how to "install" GlassFish Server 3 from its zip distribution](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-7690/ghmxb?l=en&a=view) and [how to start using GlassFish Server 3](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-7689?l=en).

There is a [summary of the work that the GlassFish Server 3 installers do](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-7690/ghmos?l=en&a=view), too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Glassfish in the manner you describe. I personally never install it - I just decompress it and run it right away...

You can download the platform independent zip distribution from [here](http://download.java.net/glassfish/v3/release/glassfish-v3.zip).

Comment: if that is the case can you point me to a .zip distribution of glassfish? I don't see any. I got a jar distribution that is basically like running a installer java class.

Comment: On the download page - https://glassfish.dev.java.net/downloads/v3-final.html - there are both installer and zip distribution of glassfish

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the original use-case is but GlassFish Embedded could be interesting to look at - http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/821-1754